# "Could not resolve keys for the segment" in Experience Analytics when using UrlRewrite module

Tags: experience-analytics, url-rewrite

Currently, using UrlRewrite (https://github.com/iamandycohen/UrlRewrite) module adapted for Sitecore 9, but I'm not able to get results due to "Could not resolve keys for the segment 'ba6e2a68-7531-4b6a-aca9-d37c8aa28c14'".

[image]

ba6e2a68-7531-4b6a-aca9-d37c8aa28c14 is "/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Dimensions/Visits/By UrlRewrite Redirect/All visits by UrlRewrite Redirect" item that already deployed (in the deployed state).

Have anyone was able to fix such issue?